# If Statement (Ngif) in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code which shows the username and picture of a Facebook user when connected to this application.

```
 <div class="item item-avatar" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-show="showProfile">
      <img src="{{user.picture}}">
        <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
        <p>Reporter</p>
  </div>
```

So, if the user is logged in using Facebook with the app, the username and profile picture will show... {{user.picture}} & {{user.name}} so what I am trying to do is to show a different case where the user is not logged in... If the user is not logged in, I want to show just plain text like "No logged in user."

So tried these codes and failed to get it

```
 <div ng-if="user.name !== '{{user.name}}'">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
          <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/5/005/06f/16e/232e2d4.jpg">
          <h2>No logged in user</h2>
      </div>
 </div>


 <div ng-if="user.name === '{{user.name}}'">
      <div class="item item-avatar" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-show="showProfile">
          <img src="{{user.picture}}">
          <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
          <p>Reporter Name</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

AND

```
<div ng-repeater="user in users">
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    <div ng-show="isExists(user)">available
        <div class="item item-avatar" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-show="showProfile">
            <img src="{{user.picture}}">
              <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
              <p>Reporter</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!isExists(user)">No logged in user</div>
</div>
```

Any solution or alternative from using ng-if or ng-repeater? Not really familiar with AngularJS.

Comment: "Not really familiar with Angular JS" - you'd better get familiar, it's a bumpy ride unless you invest in some learning via NG-Book or some other resource!

Comment: Also, if your directive / controller are set up right, your `ng-if` should be simple: `<div ng-if="user.name'">` (to show if the user name is set) and `<div ng-if="! user.name">`  (to show if the user name is not set)

Comment: Do you have a way to determine if user is logged in or not?, Can you post your controller code (specifically for the isExists(user) function)?

Comment: Why are you trying to compare something to itself (incorrectly)?  both "user.name"s refer the $scope.user.name or this.user.name, depending on how you use your controller.

Comment: Also, use ng-repeat.  ng-repeater does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the "handlebars" syntax inside Angular expressions. For instance, this is correct:

```
<div id="{{user.name}}" ng-if="user.name">{{user.name}}</div>
```

This is incorrect:

```
<div id="{{user.name}}" ng-if="{{user.name}}">{{user.name}}</div>
```

Make sure you keep your web browser's Javascript console open. This will highlight any errors for you.

The comparison you're using -- `"user.name !== '{{user.name}}'"` -- won't work. More specifically, `user.name` will *never* equal `'{{user.name}}'`. That's because you're telling Angular to compare the username with the actual string "{{user.name}}". It's the same as doing something like this:

```
var myVariable = 42;
if(myVariable === "myVariable"){
  // do something
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're going for there, anyway... The username is *always* going to equal the username, in the same way that `myVariable` will always equal `myVariable`, and `42` will always equal `42`.

```
var myVariable = 42;
myVariable === "myVariable";
// false
myVariable === myVariable;
// true
42 === "42";
// false
42 === 42;
// true
42 == "42";
// true
myVariable === 42;
// true
myVariable === "42";
// false
myVariable == "42";
// true
myVariable === true;
// false
myVariable == true;
// false
```

If you just want to check whether `user.name` exists, then try this syntax:

```
<div ng-if="user.name">The user is logged in!</div>
<div ng-if="!user.name">The user is not logged in.</div>
```

Comment: Can I do it this way? Example: <div id="{{user.name}}" ng-if="user.name !== 'user.name' "> or <div id="{{user.name}}" ng-if="user.name !== user.name "> (w/o quotes)

Comment: @KylieJ I just edited my response to address your comment!